# Spring Hibernate: Entity seems not persisted, no failures either

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

My model is

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@Entity
public class Network extends AbstractEntity {
    private long networkId;

    private String name;

    private boolean active;

    private DateTime createdAt;

    private String createdBy;

    private DateTime updatedAt;

    private String updatedBy;
    ...
}
```

`AbstractEntity` is

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final AbstractEntity abstractEntity = (AbstractEntity) obj;

        return id.equals(abstractEntity.id);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

I have `Repository` where I want to add entity. I do

```
@Repository
public class NetworkRepositoryImpl implements NetworkRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public List<Network> findAll() {
        //noinspection JpaQlInspection
        final Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Network e");
        return (List<Network>)query.getResultList();
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Network save(@Nonnull final Network network) {
        if (network.getId() == null) {
            entityManager.persist(network);
            return network;
        } else {
            return entityManager.merge(network);
        }
    }
}
```

and I `Test` it as

```
@Test
public void testAllNetworks() {
    final Network network = new Network(1, "US", true, DateTime.now());
    final Network networkInDb = networkRepository.save(network);
    assertNotNull(networkInDb.getId());
    final List<Network> networks = networkRepository.findAll();
    assertTrue(networks.isEmpty());
}
```

my `ApplicationConfig` looks like

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder embeddedDatabaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        embeddedDatabaseBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);
        return embeddedDatabaseBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.org.comma.persistence");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("test-comma-pu");

        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

My test fails on line

```
    assertNotNull(networkInDb.getId());
```

meaning the entity is not persisted

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using wrong annotation.

I was using

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
```

instead, what I needed was

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Atleast I see it try persisting and failing somewhere else

Comment: :) happens to all of us. Fyi if you use STS an orange semi-circular arrow should appear if the `@Transactional` is effecive: http://i.imgur.com/WZ2cFFD.png

Comment: Thanks @gerrytan, I use IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 0):

If your test fails because Id value is null, then it is expected behavior.

When hibernate persist an entity, it will not fetch the auto-generated key value automatically. You should either find the entity again or refresh it manually.

In similar situation, I usually refresh the entity like below.

```
entityManager.persist(network);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.refresh(network);
```

P.S: You should flush before refreshing to make it reliable.

Comment: I don't think so, his repository method had `@Transactional` so that should automatically flush at the end of invocation

Comment: Yes, it will flush at the end of the transaction. But if you want the auto-generated value to be fetched before end-of-transaction, then you would need to flush and refresh the entity. By default, hibernate will not fetch auto-generated key value when persisting an entity.